# USB Drives only mounting when login to GUI not via SSH session

Tags: usb, mount, ssh

I recently upgraded from 14.04.3 -> 16.04 and am noticing some strange behavior with my USB drives.  In 14.04.3 I could restart my system and login via SSH and I would see my USB drives mounted, but in 16.04 I don't see them when I login via SSH.  I have to login via the GUI and then I can see my drives get mounted (can see this via dmesg when I login to GUI)

```
  4.890411] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[    4.890455] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready
[  555.005083] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4024.0004: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
[  562.798702] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[  562.798833] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[  563.382801] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  563.412568] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  563.526803] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  563.608786] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```